# svelte - import Info from './Info.svelte' with typescript

Tags: typescript, svelte

I have followed the guide in https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-and-typescript

```
npx degit sveltejs/template svelte-typescript-app
cd svelte-typescript-app
node scripts/setupTypeScript.js
```

If i add

```
<script lang="ts">

    import Info from './Info.svelte';

</script>
```

Too App.svelte I get

> Could not resolve './components/Todos.svelte' from src\App.svelte

I have attempted to look though the reports on github and cant not determine how to add this.

Comment: Please add your directory structure. Also you are importing *Info.svelte* and it complains about *components/Todos.svelte* why?

Comment: Thank you. I thought that was a built in component.